# "unterminated string literal" In FireFox Console Log?

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why it's showing me a error message in Firefox Console Log. When I load the login.php page then it's showing me a error message is something like that :

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var rie = '7c5c0f66034a105055511059115603131907460d511059095b1c4c414c6
```

If I delete following script then it's doesn't show any error message. So I'm sure It's all about following script issues. Can you tell me why it's occurring this error message as I'm a new In Javascript. Thanks for your help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //Hide image on page load
$('#loaderAnim').hide();
$('#login_process').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#loaderAnim').show(); // Show it before making ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login_process.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#loaderAnim').hide(); // Hide when done 
            $('#success').html('');
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                if (key !== 'error') {
                    $('#success').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
                }
            });
            if (!data.error) {
                $('#hide').hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                    window.location.href = "index.php";
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Update (login.php page):**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['front_username']) && isset($_SESSION['front_password']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
header('Location:users/index.php');
exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo SITE_NAME; ?></title>
<link href="style/design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/menu-front.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php require_once("notice.php"); ?>
<div id="wraper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">

<?php require_once("menu.php"); ?>

<h2>Login to manage your contacts.</h2>
<img id="loaderAnim" src="images/loading-image.gif" style="display:none;"/>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <form id="login_process">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="front_username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="front_password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LogIn" class="submit"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>    
        <td colspan="2">Forgot your password ? Click <a href="forgotpass.php">here.</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<!--<script src="include/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript">
//Hide image on page load
$('#loaderAnim').hide(); 

$('#login_process').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$('#loaderAnim').show(); // Show it before making ajax call
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'login_process.php',
data: $(this).serialize(),
dataType: 'json',      

success: function (data) {
   $('#loaderAnim').hide(); // Hide when done 
   $('#success').html('');
   $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

    if(key !== 'error') {
            $('#success').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');           

    }  
}); 


    if( ! data.error) {     
        $('#hide').hide();              
         setTimeout(function () {
         $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);        
           window.location.href = "index.php"; 
    },     2000); 
        }

   }
});

});

</script>


<?php require_once("include/footer.php"); ?>


        </div><!--content-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!--wraper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see that snippet in your script at all.

Comment: looks like either the `data: $(this).serialize()` or (more likely) when jQuery parses the result of the ajax call to json. Can you check the raw response of the ajax call using the Network tab in Dev Tools to see if something like that long hash is in there?

Comment: This error message is showing on Firefox Console Log.

Comment: @Rhumborl It's showing when I load the page. Like login.php page.

Comment: The error should point to a script and a position. Please tell us more.

Comment: @Bergi I updated my questions. It's full login.php page code.

Comment: @Rhumborl can you check my update questions. You can find full code.

Comment: I rather meant the details of the error message. Also, we'd need to see the HTML which the browser receives not the PHP which generates it.